# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When running `npm start`, webpack is throwing an error:

```
ERROR in ./src/style/main.less 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @import "header.less";
| @color: #f5adad;
| body {
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-27
```

In my `main.less` file I'm doing:

```
@import "header.less";
@color: #f5adad;
body {
  background-color: @color;
}
```

In my `header.less` file I'm doing:

```
.header {
    background-color: #3d3d;
  }
```

In my `index.js` file I'm doing:

```
import "./style/main.less";
```

And my `webpack.config.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'less-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

My `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "react-config-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "eslint-fix": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "less-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.1"
  }
}
```

Also, because I think file structure might be related, my file structure looks like:
[image: file_structure]

Can anyone make a recommendation on how I can fix the problem? I'm too new to webpack even suggest where the root cause might be.

Comment: I don’t remember where webpack looks for the config if you don’t explicitly specify. If you move the config up a dir so it’s at the same level as package.json does it work? Either that or explicitly specify the config path with `--config ./src/webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is named incorrectly. The `p` and `b` are in the wrong positions. Use `webpack.config.js` instead of `wepback.config.js`

Another issue is that your file is inside the `src/` directory - it needs to be moved to be inside the `REACT-CONFIG-TUTORIAL` directory

Comment: astute observation, ty. getting a different error that i'm working thru now... Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'contentBase'.

Comment: This solved my initial problem so will mark answered and open a separate question for further issues, thank you!

Comment: @NicholasZozaya that's because your webpack is version 5 - `contentBase` has been changed from standalone to requiring `static: {}` in version 4